# Creating a new column based off contents of others columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, shown here.

[image]

I want to create a new column called `Result`

Result should be created based off the following rules.

1. Return the value that is shown the most based off columns `D,F,M,P`
2. If there is a tie between `IG` and `HY`, return `HY`.
3. Do not count `NaN` as a value.

My resulting dataframe would like this:

[image]

```
 df_start = pd.DataFrame({'P':['IG','HY','IG',np.nan,'HY'], 'M':['HY','HY','IG', np.nan,'IG'], 'F':['HY',np.nan,'HY', np.nan,'IG'],'D':['IG','IG','IG', 'HY','IG']})

 df_result = pd.DataFrame({'Result':['HY','HY','IG', 'HY','IG'],'P':['IG','HY','IG',np.nan,'HY'], 'M':['HY','HY','IG', np.nan,'IG'], 'F':['HY',np.nan,'HY', np.nan,'IG'],'D':['IG','IG','IG', 'HY','IG']}
```

Comment: Can you post dataframes in textual format, rather than images? Simply copy and paste it here.

Comment: Hi Welcome on SO. Please have a look at [mcve](/help/mcve) and [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i posted the code snippet

Comment: Why return `HY` over `IG`? What's the logic there?

Answer (score 2):

Use `mode`:

```
df_start['Result']= df_result.mode(1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Output:

```
     P    M    F   D Result
0   IG   HY   HY  IG     HY
1   HY   HY  NaN  IG     HY
2   IG   IG   HY  IG     IG
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  HY     HY
4   HY   IG   IG  IG     IG
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is the following.  Maybe it is not the most elegant but it works.
There is only one problem, if in one line you have ALL NaN then you will get "HY" for that line.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_start = pd.DataFrame({'P':['IG','HY','IG',np.nan,'HY'], 'M':['HY','HY','IG', np.nan,'IG'], 'F':['HY',np.nan,'HY', np.nan,'IG'],'D':['IG','IG','IG', 'HY','IG']})

def count_winner(words):
    igc=0
    hyc=0

    for i in words:
        if(i=="IG"):
            igc+=1
        elif(i=="HY"):
            hyc+=1
    if(igc<=hyc):
        return("HY")
    else:
        return("IG")

words=df_start.to_string(header=False, index=False, index_names=False).split('\n')

words=[i.split("   ") for i in words]
winners=[count_winner(i) for i in words]
df_start["Result"]=winners
```

Answer (score 0):

## Expanded Solution

If you wanted to count each of the uniques values in the data frame and determine which one occurs most often, you could use the code below.

### Details

Working from your given starting data frame, the NaN values are converted to strings so that they can be compared. Then, the numpy method for finding unique values is used on the data frame. This values are then used to create a new column for each unique value with the count of that value in the row.

The second for loop goes through the rows in the new df finding the max of each row and comparing the name of that column to the list of unique values.

### Input

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_start = pd.DataFrame({'P':['IG','HY','IG',np.nan,'HY'], 'M':['HY','HY','IG', np.nan,'IG'], 'F':['HY',np.nan,'HY', np.nan,'IG'],'D':['IG','IG','IG', 'HY','IG']})
df = df_start

df = df.fillna("NaN")
values = np.unique(df[df.columns].values)

# Create new df for storing counts
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Count occurence of each value 
for value in values:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        new_df.at[index,value] = int(row.values.tolist().count(value))

# Find max for each value
for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
    new_df.at[index,'Max'] = max(row.values.tolist())
    for value in values:
        if new_df.at[index,'Max'] == new_df.at[index,value]:
            new_df.at[index,'Result'] = value

# Combine the data frames
df = pd.concat([df,new_df],axis=1)
```

### Ouput:

```
    D    F    M    P   HY   IG  NaN  Max Result
0  IG   HY   HY   IG  2.0  2.0  0.0  2.0     IG
1  IG  NaN   HY   HY  2.0  1.0  1.0  2.0     HY
2  IG   HY   IG   IG  1.0  3.0  0.0  3.0     IG
3  HY  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  0.0  3.0  3.0    NaN
4  IG   IG   IG   HY  1.0  3.0  0.0  3.0     IG
```

### Cons

It's not as elegant as @Scott's solution, but it does add some capability if you want to do something with the number of occurrences of each.

It also doesn't address picking `HY` over `IG`, but that can't be done programmatically without knowing the logic behind it.